# Swing: How can I display a Splash Screen before the main class?

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen

I've created a splash screen class which basically loads and runs a GIF title file for a couple of seconds. How would I get this to display prior to the main class?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            accountGUI inst = new accountGUI();
            inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            inst.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}

public accountGUI() {...
```

Comment: Use a [`SplashScreen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main class, add a call to your splash screen in the first line. that way it will run the splash screen, then run your what is needed in the main class.